# Which type of redshift does the equation $\Delta \lambda / \lambda = v/c$ apply to?

Tags: doppler-effect, redshift

Which type of redshift does the equation:
$$\Delta \lambda / \lambda = v/c$$
apply to, that which results from the Doppler effect, or that which results from cosmological expansion?

Does it even apply to a particular type of the two? What exactly are the conditions of its applicability?

Answer (score 1):

It applies to both so long as $v \ll c$ and if you are interpreting the observed redshift of an object as a line of sight velocity.